# How to check and copy  for newly added content in a .txt file

Tags: windows, c#-4.0

I need to create a file watcher which will look up a newly added file in directory for newly added data.

When ever new data is adding to a `.jrn` file.The newly added data should copy to a temporary file. I am using window service (`C#`) to develop this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by following the below steps:

1. Create a timer in order to check any new file created
2. Use the substring method to get new added content
3. Swap the last added two contents